# Linked Lists - What can cause an address allocated with malloc to never actually be assigned?

Tags: c, data-structures, memory-management, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm creating a linked list and somewhere down the ladder I am not properly assigning the addresses to chain them together.

There is no compile time error, but a mistake in my code becomes apparent when I try to print the `list.head->next` node. The print result is an address of `00000000`.

Why is `list.head->next` not being assigned to?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


struct Node 
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct List 
{
    struct Node* head;
} list;


void insert_node(struct Node *new_node) 
{
    if (list.head == NULL)
    {
        list.head = new_node;
    }

    else 
    {
        struct Node *temp = list.head->next;

        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp = new_node;  
    }
}

struct Node* create_node(int data)
{
    static int node_number = 0;

    struct Node * new_node= malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    printf("Node inside function %d - address:  %p\n", node_number++, new_node);

    return new_node;
}


int main()
{
    struct Node *a = create_node(11);
    struct Node *b = create_node(12);

    insert_node(a);
    insert_node(b);

    printf("%p\n", list.head->next);
}
```

Comment: Where in your code do you think it *should* be assigned to?  When you trace it with a debugger, why doesn't that happen?

Comment: Setting `temp = new_node;` does not change the `next` member of any node in the list.

Comment: The debugger didn't tell me anything that I could personally interpret an answer from. It compiled and ran which is part of my confusion.In the `insert_node` function the while loop continues until it finds an available slot for  the `new_node`. If `list.head->next`  is available the loop breaks and the new_node is assigned to that spot. I did two instances of an insert so `list.head` was assigned to by the first insert, but now `list.head->next` which is the next available slot isn't properly assigning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the function insert_node in the else statement

```
else {
        struct Node *temp = list.head->next;

        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp = new_node;  
    }
```

there is changed the local variable temp that is not connected to the list.

You need to write

```
else {
        struct Node *temp = list.head;

        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp->next = new_node;  
    }
```

Pay attention to that it is a bad idea to make the function depend on the global variable `list`. In this case the function is unable to deal with other lists. So for each list as for example when in a program there are used two lists you need to write a separate function duplicating code.

The function could be defined at least the following way as it is shown below.

```
void insert_node( struct List *list, struct Node *new_node ) 
{
    struct Node **current = &list->head;

    while ( *current != NULL ) current = &( *current )->next;

    *current = new_node;
}

struct Node * create_node( int data )
{
    static unsigned int node_number = 0;

    struct Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );

    if ( new_node != NULL )
    {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = NULL;

        printf("Node inside function %u - address:  %p\n", node_number++, ( void * )new_node);
    }

    return new_node;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the else part, you iterate the list to its end and assign your temp new value,
it doesn't have any effect because temp is  your local variable, instaed you should iterate to one before the last, and set value to temp->next;

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


struct Node 
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct List 
{
    struct Node* head;
} list;


void insert_node(struct Node *new_node) 
{
    if (list.head == NULL)
    {
        list.head = new_node;
    }

    else 
    {
        struct Node *temp = list.head;

        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp->next = new_node;
    }
}

struct Node* create_node(int data)
{
    static int node_number = 0;

    struct Node * new_node= malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    printf("Node inside function %d - address:  %p\n", node_number++, new_node);

    return new_node;
}


int main()
{
    struct Node *a = create_node(11);
    struct Node *b = create_node(12);

    insert_node(a);
    insert_node(b);

    printf("%p\n", list.head->next);
}
```